# if statement inside for or while loop

Tags: c++

I have loops who isn't working

it's only shows the first cout enter 1 student info

or ether it skips the loop and do everything under it

can you please help

```
int x = 1;

    while (x <= 10) {
        ++x;
        if (x = 1) {
            cout << "enter 1 student info";
            cin >> name >> first >> second >> final>>id;
        } else if (x = 2) {
            cout << "enter 2 student info";
            cin >> name1 >> first1 >> second1 >> final1 >> id1;
        } else if (x = 3) {
            cout << "enter 3 student info";
            cin >> name2 >> first2 >> second2 >> final2 >> id2;
        } else if (x = 4) {
            cout << "enter 4 student info";
            cin >> name3 >> first3 >> second3 >> final3 >> id3;
        }
    }
```

...

```
   for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
            if (x = 1) {
                cout << "enter 1 student info";
                cin >> name >> first >> second >> final>>id;
            }
            if (x = 2) {
                cout << "enter 2 student info";
                cin >> name1 >> first1 >> second1 >> final1 >> id1;
            }
            if (x = 3) {
                cout << "enter 3 student info";
                cin >> name2 >> first2 >> second2 >> final2 >> id2;
            }
            if (x = 4) {
                cout << "enter 4 student info";
                cin >> name3 >> first3 >> second3 >> final3 >> id3;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

I just show you the 1st wrong if where you use `=` (assignment operator) instead of `==` (equal operator)

```
int x=1;

while (x<=10)
{++x;
    if(x==1)
```

For more info look at cpp reference or [wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: "affectation operator" that's a new one